# How to wrap quantmod's getSymbols() in tryCatch

Tags: r, quantmod

I used the sample code from one of the threads on this site to create a small program that downloads stock data from yahoo using `getSymbols` from the quantmod package. But when I modify the code to add `tryCatch` (I am doing this in two different ways), it doesn't return any data. I hope I have not put too many details but wanted to make sure that I give all the information.

Here is the working code (followed by non-working code which does not return any data):

```
###################### Working code################
library(quantmod)
library(plyr)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

#Data structure that contains stock quote objects
stockData <- new.env()
#Assign dates to set range for stock quotes
sDate <- as.Date("2012-09-04")
eDate <- as.Date("2014-09-02")

#Assign a vector of ticker symbols
symbols <- c("BIL","VGSH","VGIT","VGLT","BND","VOO","VTI","VT")

# download data
l_ply(symbols, function(sym) try(getSymbols(sym,env = stockData,src = "yahoo", 
                                            from = sDate, to = eDate))) 
# Now extract the data from the environment and store in a list.
symbols <- symbols[symbols %in% ls(envir = stockData)]

# sym.list 
sym.list = llply(symbols, ge

t,stockData)
names(sym.list) <- symbols
```

The following two cases do not return any data:

1. Create a function called `getYahooTickerData` which calls 
   `getSymbols` within `tryCatch`. This does not return any data.
2. Assuming there was an issue with passing environments between functions, I replaced the `try` in the above working code with `tryCatch` instead of `try`, but it still doesn't work.

First, case 1:

```
###################################Case 1################################
library(quantmod)
library(plyr)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

#Data structure that contains stock quote objects
stockData <- new.env()
#Assign dates to set range for stock quotes
sDate <- as.Date("2012-09-04")
eDate <- as.Date("2014-09-02")

#Assign a vector of ticker symbols
symbols <- c("BIL","VGSH","VGIT","VGLT","BND","VOO","VTI","VT")

getYahooTickerData <- function(ticker,startDate,endDate,envmt) {
    tryCatch(
        getSymbols(
              Symbols=ticker, 
              env = envmt, 
              from = startDate, 
              to = endDate,
              src = "yahoo",
         ),
         error=function(error_message) {
              message("error getting data")
              message(ticker)
         }, 
         warning=function(warning_message) {
              message("there was a warning for ticker ")
              message(ticker)
         }
    )
}# end of function getYahooTickerData

l_ply(symbols, function(sym) getYahooTickerData(sym,sDate,eDate,envmt=stockData))

# Now extract the data from the environment and store in a list.
symbols <- symbols[symbols %in% ls(envir = stockData)]

# sym.list 
sym.list = llply(symbols, get,stockData)
names(sym.list) <- symbols
```

In this case, `sym.list` is empty.  Now for case 2:

```
################Case 2###################################
library(quantmod)
library(plyr)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

#Data structure that contains stock quote objects
stockData <- new.env()
#Assign dates to set range for stock quotes
sDate <- as.Date("2012-09-04")
eDate <- as.Date("2014-09-02")

#Assign a vector of ticker symbols
symbols <- c("BIL","VGSH","VGIT","VGLT","BND","VOO","VTI","VT")

# download data
l_ply(symbols, function(sym) {
    tryCatch(
        getSymbols(sym,env = stockData,
                   src = "yahoo",
                   from = sDate,
                   to = eDate),
        error=function(error_message) {
             message("error getting data for symbol")
             message(sym)
        }, 
        warning=function(warning_message) {
             message("warning for symbol")
             message(sym)
        }
    )
})
# Now extract the data from the environment and store in a list.
symbols <- symbols[symbols %in% ls(envir = stockData)]

# sym.list 
sym.list = llply(symbols, get,stockData)
names(sym.list) <- symbols
```

In this case too, `sym.list` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

for errors, you'll want to include the desired return value when an error occurs. For warnings, you're actually not catching errors but working with condition handlers. So a relatively complete example is

```
withCallingHandlers({
    tryCatch({
        warning("a warning")
        stop("an error")
    }, error=function(e) {
        ## catch the error
        message(conditionMessage(e))
        ## signal with appropriate return value
        NA
    })
}, warning=function(w) {
    ## handle the warning...
    message(conditionMessage(w))
    ## then continue from where the warning occurred
    invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
})
```

Resulting in output

```
a warning
an error
[1] NA
```

Comment: Martin, I am not able to figure out how to modify my code from your response. Will it be possible for you to copy my non-working code sample, modify it, and post it here. Thanks.

Comment: @RajiveJain I'd be happy to, but can you please first clean up your code to contain the minimal code needed to reproduce your `getSymbol()` function call (no need for plyr or quantmod, for instance?).

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured out why the tryCatch was not working with getSymbols(). 
getSymbols() always gives a warning (even when warnings=FALSE option is selected) and that's why the warning function is always invoked. I removed the warnings block from tryCatch and the code worked. 
Since the code works when I remove the warning block from tryCatch, I am assuming that is the correct reason.